# How to redirect API call to another API which will return the response to the requester directly

Tags: python, django, rest

*CLIENT Side:*
UserA requests GET /file/from/some/location

*SERVER Side:*
UserA request will hit the **API1** which will generate a **URL** and redirect the user to **API2** the API will take the generated URL and return the file to the user directly without sending a response to the API1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `redirect` shortcut in Django to redirect to call to the other url:

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^/file/from/some/location$', views.api_1_view, name='api_1_view')
url(r'^/file/from/some/other/second/location$', views.api_2_view, name='api_2_view')
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def api_1_view(request):
    url_for_api_2 = reverse('api_2_view')
    return redirect(url_for_api_2)

def api_2_view(request):
    # do stuff
    # return the file
```

Comment: what if my url_for_api_2 is not present on the same Django App. Lets assume the url is `http://squid.com/release/some_file.tar` (storage location). And I want to return this file to client as a response.

Without bothering the middle API

Comment: redirect() accepts any URL. I'm not certain if the `reverse()` function will work across apps as you have it set up, but all that does is return the exact URL. If you have another way to get the URL, you can use that and pass the result in redirect() no problem.